# Extension method not found (not an assembly reference issue)

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I have the following extension method:

```
public static EntitySet<T> ToEntitySetFromInterface<T, U>(this IList<U> source)
    where T : class, U
{
    var es = new EntitySet<T>();
    IEnumerator<U> ie = source.GetEnumerator();
    while (ie.MoveNext())
    {
        es.Add((T)ie.Current);
    }
    return es;
}
```

and Im attempting to use it as follows:

```
   List<IItemMovement> p = new List<IItemMovement>();
    EntitySet<ItemMovement> ims = p.ToEntitySetFromInterface<ItemMovement, IItemMovement>();
```

where ItemMovement implements IItemMovement. The compiler complains:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a
>   definition for 'ToEntitySetFromInterface' and no extension method
>   'ToEntitySetFromInterface' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

No I'm not missing a reference. If I just type the name of the static class containing the method it pops up and so does the extension method. Thnx

Comment: im not sure List<Implementation> list = new List<Interface>(); would compile?

Comment: otherwise that code works for me (with a mocked ItemMovement and IItemMovement

Comment: I believe this question has nothing to do with intellisense. If you can't compile it then it's hardly intellisense's fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me, and its a direct copy of your code, minus the ItemMovement and its interface, so perhaps something is wrong with that part?

```
public class TestClient
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new List<IItem>();
        p.Add(new Item { Name = "Aaron" });
        p.Add(new Item { Name = "Jeremy" });

        var ims = p.ToEntitySetFromInterface<Item, IItem>();

        foreach (var itm in ims)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(itm);
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}

public class Item : IItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public interface IItem
{
}

public static class ExtMethod
{
    public static EntitySet<T> ToEntitySetFromInterface<T, U>(this IList<U> source) where T : class, U
    {
        var es = new EntitySet<T>();
        IEnumerator<U> ie = source.GetEnumerator();
        while (ie.MoveNext())
        {
            es.Add((T)ie.Current);
        }
        return es;
    }
}
```

Comment: O.k. I feel really stupid now. It wasn't an assembly ref issue but it was a using issue. I copied your code and it worked. But then when I copied it to the same class file as above code it didn't I thought I had discounted the namespace issue by testing whether i could call the extension methods class LinqExtensions and indeed I could. So not sure how i can call that class without using fully qualified namespace and yet not be able to use extension method if using wasn't properly declared? Either way done now. Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

This part of the compiler error is the key:  "no extension method 'ToEntitySetFromInterface' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'".

Your `ToEntitySetFromInterface<T,U>` extension method is defined to accept an `IList<U>` but you're attempting to call it with a `List<T>` rather than an `IList<T>`.  The compliler isn't finding your extension method because the type doesn't match.

Comment: Hi there, I don't understand what u mean by List<T>? I'm calling ToEntitySetFromInterface<T, U>(this IList<U> source) so the IList type is defined by the type of U which is IItemMovement i.e. ILIst<IItemMovement>. Since (this IList<U> source) determines the type that the extension method can be applied to which in this case is IList<IItemMovement> and p = IList<IItemMovement> I don't quite follow what you're saying. Note above I have: List<IItemMovement> but even if change that to IList<IItemMovment> I still get the same problem/error.